# How to Update Object inside Mono<T>

Tags: spring-webflux

I have below code inside a Handler and after extracting the user i want to update the user object with the password
How do i do something like below 
user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));

```
  public Mono<ServerResponse> saveUser(ServerRequest request) 
 {
    Mono<User> user = request.bodyToMono(User.class);
    // How to Set the Password to user 
    **//user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));**

    return ServerResponse.ok().body(this.userRepository.insert(user), User.class);
}
```

Comment: try to use onNext : request.bodyToMono(User.class).doOnNext(user -> user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword())))

Answer (score 2):

In theory, you could just do the following:

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> saveUser(ServerRequest request) {
    Mono<User> user = request.bodyToMono(User.class)
        .map(user -> user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword())));

    return ServerResponse.ok().body(this.userRepository.insert(user), User.class);
}
```

But this can be seen as a specific use case; I think password encoders are designed to be CPU intensive and take some time, for security reasons. Doing expensive CPU operations on the web exchange pipeline is not advised, as your application won't scale very well: the few threads allocated to handle requests will be busy doing authentication stuff vs. handling HTTP requests.

So in that case you use insert a `publishOn(Schedulers.elastic())` operator right before the `.map` encoding; this will schedule those CPU intensive operations on an elastic Scheduler (see the [Reactor reference doc on Schedulers](http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#schedulers)).